# Raw javascript instead of jquery (example follows)

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first question here. I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent("li").css({textDecoration: "line-through"});
        return false;
    });
 });
```

that works just fine. It strikes through the parent li of any clicked anchor (there are many anchors and lists in the html, not just one). But i want just this functionality, nothing else. Isn't this an overkill to include the whole jquery library?

Unfortunateley i don't know raw javascript very well, can someone convert this for me? I would be grateful.

EDIT: Wow i am amazed at speed and the quality of the answers! So first of all a big THANKS to all of you! I will either go for jonathon's (edit2: roland's) solution or just include jquery after all. Thanks again!

Comment: "If it ain't broke..." You can convert it to pure Javascript, but you run the risk of breaking cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I'd try to step through the JS code and see which jQuery functions are used for that script, and delete everything else.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: well generally speaking yes this is good advice. But what the OP is trying to achieve can be solved in a fairly straightforward browser independent way. (assuming basic DOM implementation)

@Dor: if the OP is indeed not well versed in javascript, stepping through jQuery is not going to make him happy. Did you? I mean, no disrespect to jQuery intended - it is one of the greatest js libs on the planet, but I would not recommend it as a beginners exercise to analyze that code.

Comment: are you absolutely sure that your webpage will never change in the future and be that way forever? Jquery will come in handy if you ever want to add new things in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will achieve it in a browser independent manner.

```
<html>

  <body onload="loaded()">
      ...content goes here....
      <script>
          function linkClickHandler(){
              var parentNode = this.parentNode;
              if(parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()==="li"){
                  parentNode.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
              }
              return false;
          }

          function loaded(){
              for (var i=0, links = document.links, numLinks = links.length; i<numLinks; i++){
                  links[i].onclick = linkClickHandler;
              }
          }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ain't the jQuery $(document).ready() method is different than window.onload() ?

Comment: Dor: perhaps. I think that for what the OP is trying to achieve, this old skool solution works just fine.

Comment: The jQuery `ready` event is quite complex: it uses the `DOMContentLoaded` event where available (reliable), a ghastly property-reading-poller hack on IE (not reliable), and everywhere else falls back to `onload` (reliable, but later to fire). If you want to run on content-loaded, the only 100% reliable method (whether jQuery or raw JavaScript) is to put the trigger `<script>` element at the end of the document.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. Unfortunately it doesnt seem to work although it doesnt give any errors in the console either. Maybe it's me doing something wrong?

Comment: @bobince: thanks, I never analyzed it, and your explanation is insightful. Just one question regarding the location of the "trigger" `<script>` element. By "at the end of the document" do you mean right before the `</body>` endtag? Or completely at the bottom, beyond the closing `</html>`? Just curious...

Comment: Nits: should be `onclick= ...` not `click`; tagname comparison should do a case folding (eg. `parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()==='li'`).

Comment: @Roland: Yes, just before `</body>` is generally best. To be outside the body would be invalid, though browsers would tend to allow it.

Comment: @bobince: thanks! and thanks! fixing the nits you pointed out...that's what I get for not testing :(

Answer (score 9):

> Isn't this an overkill to include the
>   whole jquery library?

You tell me.  You could serve the library hosted by Google, which may be already cached in the client-side.

In my opinion, being consistent is the key.  If you are used to jQuery, then why not continue to use it?  Your code will be easier to maintain.

You might find one of my earlier questions interesting: [When is it acceptable to use jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716403/when-is-it-acceptable-to-use-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Non-jQuery approach:

```
    [...your html...]

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var anchors    = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var numAnchors = anchors.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < numAnchors; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            anchor.onclick = function() {           
                var parentEl = this.parentNode;
                if(parentEl.tagName.toLowerCase() == "li"){
                    parentEl.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
                }
                return false;   
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

You don't even need a onload handler for the page load when you add it to the very bottom of your document.

Answer (score 1):

IF you do it through raw javascript you are going to need to add a onclick event to each anchor and an id to each li

```
<ul>   
    <li id='distinctID'><a href="javascript:strikeThrough('distinctId')">Click Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

that's your html change

```
function strikeThrough(id){
    var li = document.getElementById(id)
    li.style. textDecoration = "line-through"
}
```

thats your javascript function

I would recommend that you just include JQuery so that you don't have to add a ton of ids to you mark up

Comment: No, you don't need inline event handler attributes, you can write `element.onclick= function` from JavaScript and this is almost always the best thing to do. Certainly don't (ever) use `javascript:` pseudo-URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're never going to do more with your website, maybe it's overkill.  Doing the equivalent of what that short blurb does in a cross-browser manner is a headache.  That's the value of using jQuery: writing something once and having it usually work without too much hassle.  If you think the extra 20KB of bandwidth for visitors to your page is an undue burden, then start reading up on event handlers, DOM, and CSS manipulation.

You say you don't know JS well...did you inherit this jQuery usage from someone else or did you copy it from an example somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Converting a seems simple function from jquery code to a raw javascript code sometimes will catch you with a cross browser bug, a bloat functions, and a possibilities that your needs will grow in the future.

Using jQuery for such a functions is not overkill, trust me. You will never now what else of jQuery neat feature that you might need in the future. jQuery is small enough in minified form, wouldn't make any differences for a page load.